# I want to revert deleted Authentified Users in some hard drive partition in Windows

Tags: windows, user-accounts, user, windows-error-reporting, error-correction

As we can see I deleted the entry of 'Authenticated Users' and 'Users' from the security tab in C: local properties. I can still use every installed program on the PC, but unable to access C:, the message is: Denied Acess, any way to revert it?

Comment: You have destroyed too many permissions on essential Windows folders. You need to reinstall Windows from scratch, and avoid doing this again.

Comment: harrymc has the right of it - there's no automated permission repair on Windows. It is technically possible to recreate the permissions yourself, but it would be a very poor use of your time. Just reinstall.

Comment: @Karu I have so many dependencies in this system. I prefer to recontrol C:

Comment: What you want to do and what you can do are not the same thing. This is a good lesson: don't mess with permissions on C drive unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot repair the damage you've done to permissions on the C drive without a reinstall of Windows. There are too many little details that cannot be known. There are the OS default permissions which are already complex and irreproducable, and then there are the permissions set by individual applications, and finally there are likely other changes you made to permissions besides simply removing the two groups you state you removed.

The correct course of action at this point is to perform a reinstall of Windows.

Comment: ... and then set up proper automated backups that would be able to completely rollback the system after such mistake. Veeam Agent is my usual recommendation, I've been using it with great success. It does complete system snapshots in background and can restore a completely destroyed OS.